# How to make an auto-complete list when I start to type in the textfield?

Tags: java, swing, autocomplete, intellij-idea, jtextfield

I have a textfield and if I want to write something to the field, it will show me the list of possible options regarding to that letter and I think this is called an auto complete.

Could someone give me an idea or a sample on how to do it?

Thanks..

Comment: Where do you want to implement it? In HTML or QT or any other GUI mode. Without this, it is difficult to answer this question

Comment: @Koran - the question is tagged (plain) java so I expect AWT/Swing

Comment: only in GUI. And then later i will use the words from my database because im making a translation program.

Comment: what GUI? even in java, it has SWT in eclipse and swing. It's different. if it's swing, it should tag swing not intellij-idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/AutocompleteComboBox.htm) is `AutoCompleteComboBox / JFextField`, and there are two classes one for [JComboBox](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html), second for [JTextField](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html), notice auto-complete functionality requires both classes for that

Comment: how can I run? it needs a main.

Comment: you have to define some array e.g List, then setDataList(myList)

Comment: check my profile I posted more than once here (autocompleted or JComboBox or Table with autocompleted combobox or  JTable with autocompleted combobox)

Comment: I already check your profile but I do not see any sample there.

Answer (score 4):

Take a combo box and listen to all changes in the textfield. On every event, read the actual content and query your source list for possible matches. Then use the result to populate the associated list.

You may want to start autocompletion once the user has entered two or three letters, otherwise the list may get too long..

Comment: is it ok if I use Jlist instead of Combo box? Do I still need to use JPopupMenu for this one?

Comment: Sure, if you accept to keep the text field separated from the list of suggestions. But usually this is done within *one* widget: you type something and the suggestions appear right below your fragments. - (2), no, with JComboBox you won't need a popup menu.

Comment: yeah.. all you said is what really I need, do you have any idea how to put the list of suggestions below the textfield? I mean do I have to use other window for this one or just make some x, y coordinations in order to appear just below the textfield when I type something to the field?

Comment: [JComboBox](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) already provides a combination of textfield and list. That's why it's called *combo box*.

Comment: Do you have any sample about autocomplete using JComboBox? even just an easy sample, I'll only just get an idea in the sample. thanks.;-)

Answer (score 1):

I feeling generous as you really should google ...

As the user types, you'd need to query your DB with a `like '<userInput>%'` and return the results into a pulldown. You probably want to wait for a pause in the user's typing so as not to hammer your DB.

In the absence of a database, a data structure that would work well for this is called a `Trie` as you can traverse it past the initial input and present all the subsequent words.

Comment: thanks but i will use only from GUI. When I type something to the textfield, a list of suggestions will appear just below the textfield. And the list of suggestions will be coming from my database but for the meantime i can try a string of array before applying it in my DB. Could you help me or any idea about this one? Thanks..

Comment: Same thing ... you're going to have to capture input from the textfield as the user types (keyevents) and search whatever data source you're using for matches. Using an array is expensive because your performance is O(n*m) (because you're going to have to search each string within the array), but for testing it would be fine.

Comment: yeah.. I already tried some unit test and now I want it to try in GUI. its quietly hard thats why I'm asking this kind of stuff. Well, I'll try what you said. tnx.. ;-)